# How do I know when all paintings are finished?

Tags: javafx-2

My program is fullscreen application. On start I use some checks and if something is wrong, error dialog is shown. I need two windows (main fullscreen, and dialog) were here and all graphics were ok.
When I use this code:

```
primaryStage.show();
/*..some checks*/
dialogStage.show();
```

.. there is no fullscreen. It's somehow overlapped by other windows.

This one works better:

```
stage.setOnShown( new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    public void handle(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
       /*..some checks*/
       dialogStage.show();        
    }
});
primaryStage.show();
```

But... I can see task panel from Windows. It becomes hidden when dialog is closed.
And also I can see default java icon there. Although I've set custom icon before.
Looks like setOnShown() is called before all graphical updates are done.
Is there any event or something to know it?

I also tried Timeline from animation to call a small delay. But without success.
The same with calling dialog from additional thread (with Platform.runLater() of course :) ). This way fullscreen hides at all.

Maybe on JavaFX8 things are better?